# Python Fabric: Keep permissions of executables when putting them to a remote machine

Tags: python, permissions, fabric

My executables lose the execute permissions after putting them to a remote server with Fabric (files are created with default permissions).

Does Fabric provide a simple way to keep the file permissions unchanged, or I need to handle them manually?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using [put](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.1/api/core/operations.html#fabric.operations.put) look at it's mirror_local_mode kwarg, or if you want some mode specifically, there is a kwarg for mode as well.  Both have blurbs on the link I provided.